# Porqué no se mantienen los últimos cambios al detener la ejecución de Flutter

Tags: flutter

Al momento de parar o desconectar el dispositivo en el que estoy ejecutando pruebas en Flutter no se guardan los últimos cambios, qué se debe configurar o qué comando se debe ejecutar para que cuando detenga o desconecte el dispositivo de pruebas se guarden los últimos cambios. Esto ya me ha pasado algunas veces, tal vez tiene que ver con algo de hot reload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Así es, solo se guardan los cambios luego de correr la aplicación, una vez que empiezas a realizar cambios usando hot-reload, lo que hace Flutter es inyectar esos cambios de código en la máquina virtual de Dart.

Luego de que la Dart Virtual Machine refresca las clases con las nuevas versiones de campos y funciones, Flutter se encarga de hacer el refresco/rebuild de el árbol de widgets, lo que permite que podamos ver rápidamente los cambios en pantalla.

Antes de desconectar el teléfono procura detener y volver a correr la aplicación para que quede con los últimos cambios que realizaste.

Puedes encontrar más info aquí: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/hot-reload

Comment: También puedes detener la aplicación y ejecutar `flutter install`