# ¿Porqué al ejecutar la app no tiene los ultimos cambios realizados en el codigo?

Tags: flutter

Después de actualizar **Flutter** a la versión **1.12.13+hotfix.9** cada que realizo un cambio en la app dicho cambio no se visualiza.

Para que se visualice el cambio tengo que realizar un `flutter clean` o una ves que ya se esta ejecutando tengo que hacer un **restart** para que muestre los nuevos cambios hechos en el código.

---

### Ejemplo:

**Si en mi código en la versión 1, tengo lo siguiente.**

```
Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
    child: Text('Entrar'),
);
```

antes de ejecutar para probar en el móvil, realizo un `flutter clean` todo se muestra correctamente en la app.

**Ahora, si realizo un cambio suponiendo que paso a versión 2 del código**

```
Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
    child: FlatButton(
        child: Text('Entrar'),
        onPressed: ()=> Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, 'home'),
    ),
);
```

Ejecuto nuevamente el app **Sin realizar `flutter clean`**, al visualizar la app me muestra el código de la **versión 1**

Anteriormente esto no pasaba y todos los cambios se aplicaban sin problema y sin tener que realizar `flutter clean`.

Debido a esto me sucede mucho que realizo cambios que son lógicos, uso los mensajes en consola u otro para visualizar el resultado, debido a este problema no puedo visualizar si funciona hasta que realice un **restart** o `flutter clean` ya que no estaba acostumbrado a realizarlo constantemente.

Me gustaría saber si existe alguna forma de solucionar este problema.

Answer (score -1):

**Los cambios que hayas realizado, deben estar salvados (guardados) antes de realizar un hot reload.** Hot reload destruye el estado de los valores y las establece en sus valores predeterminados.

Mientras que el hot restart si te funciona, por que este primero guarda todos los cambios en el proyecto y luego continua inyectando ficheros de código fuente actualizados en la Máquina Virtual(VM) Dart en ejecución.

Para mas informacion: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/vs-code#hot-reload-vs-hot-restart

Comment: Hmm creo que no se refiere a eso, en todo caso ya existe una respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/294435/porqué-no-se-mantienen-los-últimos-cambios-al-detener-la-ejecución-de-flutter/294466#294466

Comment: @diegoveloper revise la respuesta antes de publicar mi pregunta, aun que se parece mucho es diferente, en mi caso es que si realice un `flutter clean` en la version 1 del código se muestra con dicha información en la app(todo bien hasta ahi), pero si hice cambio y ejecuto el app normal **sin hacer `clean`**, me sige mostrando el codigo de la versión 1 y no de lo nuevo.

Comment: haces cambios en código dart o código de plataforma kotlin/java , swift/objectiv-c ?

Comment: @diegoveloper los cambios son en codigo dart, actualice mi pregunta para tratar de que se entienda mejor mi problema

Comment: `flutter clean` elimina los directorios `build/` y `.dart_tool/` . Lo cual permite que puedes ver todos los cambios efectuados. Si el cambio es en las dependencia es necesario un flutter clean o hot restart.

Comment: @Richard no me ha sucedido ese error, puedes ver si pasa lo mismo en iOS/Android o solo en una plataforma? lo otro es que puedas hacer upgrade la versión de flutter

Comment: Tal y como menciona @diegoveloper es muy posible que upgrading resulva tu problema. _This release is full of fixes, with an unprecedented 6,339 issues closed since our 1.12 stable release._